# How should the SENDER header be used in Emails

Tags: email

I've got a web app which I'm sending emails from. I want the emails to appear to come from users of the system, but guessing that these will appear as spoofed emails as they aren't coming from where they are saying they come from.

I've looked around and it appears that the SENDER header fits the bill. Is this a good solution? Also which way round should it be used? SENDER is the users email? or SENDER is the an email address from the domain I'm sending from?

Thanks in advance

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who is doing the sending of the emails? From your description I would guess that some action of a user triggers sending an email. In that case, the user's email address belongs in the `From` header, and in any case, an email address for your web app should be in the `Sender` header because that is doing the actual sending of the email.

Of course, this is how it ideally works. I have encountered broken email programs that actually use the `Sender` header for replies if that is present instead of `From`, so if the receivers of the emails start replying to you, you will probably need to reconsider, but for now go with the "correct" approach.

Comment: Great, that's what I thought. You are right, the user emails a friend in this case through the web app. So it's 'from' the user, but 'sent' by the app.